# How can I write my Windows Phone app to use wp 8 features but be backward compatible with wp 7

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'd like to use some wp8-specific apis but I don't want to drop support for wp7 in my app.

In particular, I'd like to do the following:

```
   if(isWindowsPhone8OrNewer)
   {
        var sp = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        sp.SpeakTextAsync("test");
   }
```

What is the best way to access the wp8 api and not have to maintain two separate versions of the app?

For example, do I need to use reflection?

Can someone please provide an example?

Many thanks!
swine

Comment: Which API's? Typically you'd want to look at them 1 by 1 and decide.  Often times its easiest to call a wrapper method that determines what to call... The new API if supported or a workaround method to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is simple: Simply don't upgrade your app to using the WP8, and you'll be free to continue maintaining your WP7 app using the WP8 SDK in VS2012.

If you want to split up your application, and start utilizing the new UI features such as the native LongListSelector, you would want to separate your UI and view logic (ViewModels, etc.) into separate assemblies.

Comment: So how do I access, for example, the new SpeechSynthesizer class in my app *if* it is running on wp8?

Comment: Use [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(v=vs.71).aspx) if you really need to. It's a folly to attempt, better to maintain two different apps, and port the changes between them during the grace period.

Comment: Better to maintain 2 different apps? Really? That's a pretty bad solution. In win32 you use LoadLibrary and dynamically call dlls. On Android you use reflection. Cmon there's gotta be a better way... Preprocessors are a hack, but still better than supporting two different apps. Perhaps having different solution/project files that reference the same source might work...

Comment: Two different solutions referencing to the same files is still equivalent of maintaining two apps.

Comment: Hmmm I guess you might have a point there :). But if I go down this route, does that mean I have to publish the app under a different app id??

Comment: No, you can maintain two versions for same app-id on the apphub

Comment: Won't that WP8-version of xap overwrite the existing WP7-version if I upload it under the same app-id? I thought once you upgrade your app (from WP7-targeted to WP8-targeted) you won't be able to keep uploading new WP7-versions of the app.

Comment: Presuming it'll be the same process as for 7.0 to 7.5, you'll be able to maintain both versions.

Comment: I just upgraded to wp8 and stopped updating my 7.5 only app. It was the easiest way... :) What Claus says about the app listing supporting multiple xaps was very helpful and that's exactly what i did.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice project for accessing some WP8 API from your WP7 project, if you are running on WP8 device:
http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/

If you want to use other new WP8 features, you have to upgrade your project to WP8.

Comment: I don't think this addressed my need. I've added more specifics to my question above. Thanks.